# Istio 1.0.2 access grafana on Browser

Tags: grafana, istio

I have deployed istio on GKE using the command :

```
 helm template istio-1.0.2/install/kubernetes/helm/istio --name istio --namespace istio-system --set global.mtls.enabled=true --set tracing.enabled=true --set servicegraph.enabled=true --set grafana.enabled=true --set telemetry-gateway.grafanaEnabled=true > istio.yaml
```

But I just dont get how to access grafana on the browser. 
and I do not want to use the port-forwarding.. that is not a real world solution.
I used the following gateway and virtualservice definition. 
But I cant  access the Grafana UI on the browser.. Any help is really appreciated

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: grafana-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use Istio default gateway implementation
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 15031
      name: http-grafana
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: grafana
spec:
  hosts:
  - "grafana-test"
  gateways:
  - grafana-gateway
  #- mesh
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: "grafana.istio-system.svc.cluster.local"
        port:
          number: 3000
```

Comment: 1. Try to use `*` in the `hosts` field of the VirtualService
2. Verify that you access the correct port - see https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/#determining-the-ingress-ip-and-ports

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.. unfortunately I am unable to mark your reply as the "accepted answer" ..you have replied rather than "answered" my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to adjust Istio `VirtualService` by changing `hosts` to the value `"*"` as per @Vadim Eisenberg suggestion.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: grafana
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - grafana-gateway
  #- mesh
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: "grafana.istio-system.svc.cluster.local"
        port:
          number: 3000
```

I've check on my GKE environment and it is working as expected:

`$ export INGRESS_HOST=$(kubectl -n istio-system get service istio-ingressgateway -o jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}')`

`$ curl -I -H "Host:grafana.istio-system.svc.cluster.local" http://$INGRESS_HOST:15031`

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 set-cookie:
>   grafana_sess=3b7c8eda239f6bb2; Path=/; HttpOnly date: Mon, 29 Oct 2018
>   13:48:14 GMT x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 6 server: envoy
>   transfer-encoding: chunked